# How do I hide horizontal lines on Access when a particular text box is empty?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report with 5 textboxes each separated by a horizontal line.

The first textbox will always be populated but I would like to suppress the viewing/printing of any of the lines after that if the 2nd textbox is empty.

I've tried this...

```
Public Function Hide_Lines()

Dim ELRep As Report
Set ELRep = Reports("EL_Report")

If ELRep.Name_2 = Null Then
Set ELRep.Line2.Visible = False
Set ELRep.Line3.Visible = False
Set ELRep.Line4.Visible = False
Set ELRep.Line5.Visible = False

End If

End Function
```

...but I get a 'Method 'Item' of object 'Reports' failed error.

Is my syntax suspect or am I barking up completely the wrong tree?

Many thanks,
Chas

Comment: ***Welcome to Stack Overflow!*** What are the lines named?  Also perhaps a screenshot would help illustrate your question.  Please take a few minutes to check out the [tour] and there are also important tips in [ask] as well as tips about **providing examples** at [mcve]. More helpful stuff [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).  You can always [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: Thanks.  I've edited my original question.

Comment: From where are you calling your `Hide_Lines` function? I assume this is supposed to be called while a report is formatting/painting/printing in which case getting a new report object every time (`Set ELRep = Reports("EL_Report")`) is probably not what you want. You want to act on an existing report object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot compare anything to Null, `= Null` won't work. Review http://allenbrowne.com/casu-12.html.

Probably a function call is unnecessary complication. Use the report Detail Section OnFormat event with:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
With Me
If IsNull(.Name_2) Then
    .Line1.Visible = False
    .Line2.Visible = False
    .Line3.Visible = False
    .Line4.Visible = False
End If
End With
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
With Me
.Line1.Visible = Not IsNull(.Name_2)
.Line2.Visible = Not IsNull(.Name_2)
.Line3.Visible = Not IsNull(.Name_2)
.Line4.Visible = Not IsNull(.Name_2)
End With
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 to 4
    Me.Controls("Line" & x).Visible = Not IsNull(Me.Name_2)
Next
End Sub
```

Be aware OnFormat event only triggers in PrintPreview or direct to printer not ReportView.

Comment: I've tried both suggestions but get the following error:  'The expression On Format you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: A problem occurred while Microsoft Access was communicating with the OLE server or ActiveX Control.'  Any further thoughts?

Comment: Nope, code works for me. I am not using an ActiveX control. Why don't you test code on a simple report that has nothing on it except four lines. The condition can be `If IsNull(Null) Then`. That's what I did.

Comment: Yep, works fine on a simple report.  I just need to find out now why it isn't working for my report.